# Counting array occurrences in an array

Tags: python, numpy, counting

Hi I have a 2d array like this

```
[[0 2]
 [0 1]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [0 1]
 [1 2]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]
 [1 3]
 [2 3]]
```

I need to count the occurrences of each array for example [0, 1] = 4, [0,2] = 1, etc. Preferably using numpy.
and then extract the max values.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.unique() will do for you

```
unique_arr, num = np.unique(arr, axis=0, return_counts=True)
```